# How to confirm if all elements are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a UI interface that show messages and after confirming them they become :"display=none", now i want to check if all the elements are been confirm meaning all hidden. so that my interface wont start.

This is the code:

this is visible:

```
<li id="announcement4" class="announcement"></li>
```

this is not visible:

```
<li id="announcement4" class="announcement" style="display: none"></li>
```

can i check via the class or type? like

```
if(all elements type li are hidden)    
if(all elements class announcement are hidden)
```

what is a good way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
if($('ul#SomeId').children(':visible').length == 0) {
   // all are hidden
}
```

or:

```
if($('li.announcement:visible').length == 0) {
       // all are hidden
    }
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtEt9/)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `is(':visible')`

```
var allLiHidden    = !$('li').is(':visible');
var allClassHidden = !$('.announcement').is(':visible')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/C5QbR/)

Comment: My bad, I thought `is()` only worked on a jQuery object containing a single element.

Comment: Every day is a school day :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - But it returns a boolean, which doesn't have a length property like some seem to think ?

Comment: I'll add a fiddle to prove it, as I'm getting downvoted while non-functioning answers are getting upvoted ?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It's the correct answer

Comment: ^^ nothing new, people upvoting crap that doesn't work !

Comment: I really wish down required a comment.

Comment: why didn't you simply use `$('li').is(':hidden');`..? why are you reversing the process here.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - On a collection, `is(':hidden')` would be true if any element is hidden, not all of them, hence `is(':visible')` which is true when any element is visible, and then reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.announcement:visible').length>0)
{
//something is visible
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to get a propery `length` from a boolean value. This would not work.

Comment: I assume you've not tried this as `is()` returns a boolean which has no `length` property.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Corrected it

Answer (score 1):

For such a query, you can use the jQuery [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, which gives you only visible elements *(everything that Consumes space in the layout)* As return.

If you then compare the amount of visible elements with the invisible, you'll see whether one is not visible.

```
if( $('.announcement').length === $('.announcement:visible').length ){
   //all visible
} else{
   //not all visible
}
```

Or

```
if( $('li').length === $('li:visible').length ){
   //all visible
} else{
   //not all visible
}
```

Comment: Typo there ---- `length`